# Matplotlib pyplot imshow puts image in button instead of where it needs to be

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib and having some problems with creating a simple gui.

The purpose of the gui is to show an image, and wait for the user to select a category so it can be saved in the appropriate location.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import pickle
import os
import cv2

path_to_first_image = "training_data/2f8ebb07-8a83-4373-973a-439217bc7f0a/0.jpg"
path_to_second_image = "training_data/2f8ebb07-8a83-4373-973a-439217bc7f0a/1.jpg"

class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.show_image(path_to_first_image)

    def next(self, event):
        self.show_image(path_to_second_image)

    def show_image(self, path):
        plt.axis('off')
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.draw()

    def other(self, event):
        pass


gui = Gui()

#buttons
axnext = plt.axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
axweird = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.15, 0.075])

bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(gui.next)

bother = Button(axweird, 'other')
bother.on_clicked(gui.other)

plt.show()
```

What the code now does:

- it displays an image, which the user can categorize into one of three categories. This works for the first image.
- When next is clicked, the next image is shown, but instead of replacing the image in the gui, it is somehow placed in one of the buttons, and I don't want that. (see images below)

When I run the script this is how it looks:
[image: Initial state]

When I click next, the next image is placed inside of a button...
[image: When I click next]

What I want it to do is replace the original image with the next one, like this: (excuse my poor photoshop skills)
[image: What I want it to do]

I have looked in the matplotlib docs and can't seem to figure out why the image would be plotted inside of the button instead of where the first image is plotted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I edited the code so it would be smaller and easier to understand, it wont look the same as in the pictures but the same "bug" happens

Comment: Comment `self.show_image()` in next function and check the results if it works. Remember, comment it in both if conditions.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago That wont work, as then nothing will happen when I click next. I tried it just to be sure, and as I expected nothing happens. The point of the next button is to display the next image, without show_image nothing will be displayed

Comment: Could you make code smaller and little sample to test?\

Comment: @Hamed_gibago I edited the code, now its just the very basic functions. The "bug"/problem still happens